# MIDI doesn't work

Tags: sound

i'm trying to use LMMS and i receive this mesage in the terminal

```
:~$ lmms
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Notice: could not set realtime priority.
Couldn't create MIDI-client, neither with ALSA nor with OSS. Will use dummy-MIDI-client.
```

there were more errors that i've fixed but i cant solve those can anybody help me
the program runs but i cant use MIDI